# Kotlin: Merge two different list into one with selected data from both lists

Tags: android, arraylist, kotlin, merge

I want to merge two list with different type and create and another list which contains data from both lists. Also, merging should only happen when identifier match(like id match in both list)

```
Employee(val employeeId: Int,
         val employeeName: String,
         val address: String)

LaptopInfo(val laptopId: Int,
         val employeeId: String,
         val team: String)

EmployeeLaptopInfo(val laptopId: Int,
         val employeeId: String,
         val employeeName: String,
         val address: String)
```

So there is list of `Employee` and `LaptopInfo` and I want to add EmployeeLaptopInfo to `List<EmployeeLaptopInfo>` only when employeeId match in both lists

```
val employeeLaptopInfoList = mutableListOf<EmployeeLaptopInfo>()
val employeeIds = employeeList.map { it.employeeId }.toSet()

lapTopInfoList.filter { employeeIds.contains(it.employeeId) }
   .map {
      val employeeLaptopInfo = EmployeeLaptopInfo(it.laptopId, laptopId.employeeId, "can't get info", "can't get info")
      employeeLaptopInfoList.add(employeeLaptopInfo)
   }
```

But this way I don't get details from both list. Is there any way to do it without using for loop and in efficient manner.

Comment: Hi :)
Function which you probably need is zip.
More information under link: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/zip.html

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I've optimized **Yoni Gibbs's** solution. The idea is to `filter` the laptops in which the `employeeId` is present in `Employee`. Then transform each `laptop` into `EmployeeLaptopInfo`.

```
data class Employee(val employeeId: Int, val employeeName: String, val address: String)

data class LaptopInfo(val laptopId: Int, val employeeId: Int, val team: String)

data class EmployeeLaptopInfo(val laptopId: Int, val employeeId: Int, val employeeName: String, val address: String)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val employees = listOf<Employee>()
    val laptops = listOf<LaptopInfo>()

    val employeesById: Map<Int, Employee> = employees.associateBy { it.employeeId }

    val result = laptops.filter { employeesById[it.employeeId] != null }.map { laptop ->
        employeesById[laptop.employeeId]?.let { employee ->
            EmployeeLaptopInfo(laptop.laptopId, laptop.employeeId, employee.employeeName, employee.address)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your classes have errors in the data type of some properties, so I changed them like this:

```
class Employee(val employeeId: Int, val employeeName: String, val address: String)
class LaptopInfo(val laptopId: Int, val employeeId: Int, val team: String)
class EmployeeLaptopInfo(val laptopId: Int, val employeeId: Int, val employeeName: String, val address: String)
```

If these are the initial lists:

```
val employeeList = mutableListOf<Employee>()
val laptopInfoList = mutableListOf<LaptopInfo>()
```

then you map `employeeList` by finding corresponding values for `employeeId` in both lists:

```
val employeeLaptopInfoList =
        employeeList.mapNotNull { emp ->
            val laptop = laptopInfoList.find { it.employeeId == emp.employeeId }
            if (laptop == null) null 
            else EmployeeLaptopInfo(
                laptop.laptopId,
                emp.employeeId,
                emp.employeeName,
                emp.address)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be best to first create two maps, one for the laptops and one for the employees, where both are keyed on the employeeId. Then you can do the following:

```
    val employees = listOf<Employee>()
    val laptops = listOf<LaptopInfo>()

    val laptopsByEmployeeId: Map<Int, List<LaptopInfo>> = laptops.groupBy { it.employeeId }
    val employeesById: Map<Int, Employee> = employees.associateBy { it.employeeId }
    val result = laptopsByEmployeeId.flatMap { (employeeId, laptops) ->
        laptops.mapNotNull { laptop ->
            employeesById[employeeId]?.let { employee ->
                EmployeeLaptopInfo(laptop.laptopId, employeeId, employee.employeeName, employee.address)
            }
        }
    }
```

This means that you're never looping round one list inside a loop round another list, which could be inefficient. Instead, you're using the maps to get at items quickly by their IDs.

(Also, as per the answer from forpas, I'm assuming that the data type for employeeId should be the same in all the classes, e.g. Int.)